# Mongodb POST response returns 0?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I got it to work on accident with out adding a `res.json(doc)` but I found that when I make a POST request I need to send a response and ever since I added that response I get 0 or null?

```
add: function(req, res) {
    //var newPlayer = new models.Team({ _id: req.params.tid }, { players: req.body });
    models.Team.update({ _id: req.params.tid }, { $addToSet: { players: req.body} }, function(err, newPlayer){
            if (err) {
                res.json({error: 'Error.'});
            } else {
                res.json(newPlayer);
            }
    });
},
```

Also tried with `findOneAndUpdate` but my POST request is showing 0 or null for the response.

I am updating an array of objects inside a collection, it's nested. Here is the SCHEMA just to be clear.

```
var Team = new Schema({
    team_name:   { type: String },
    players: [
        {
            player_name:  { type: String },
            points:       { type: Number },
            made_one:     { type: Number },
            made_two:     { type: Number },
            made_three:   { type: Number },
            missed_one:   { type: Number },
            missed_two:   { type: Number },
            missed_three: { type: Number },
            percentage:   { type: Number },
            assists:      { type: Number },
            rebounds:     { type: Number },
            steals:       { type: Number },
            blocks:       { type: Number },
            fouls:        { type: Number },  
            feed:         { type: String },
            facebook_id:  { type: Number }
        }
    ]
});
```

So my question is does anyone have any idea why I am getting that response 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update method does not return the document in the response. The callback arguments are `(err, numAffected)` where `numAffected` is the number of documents touched by the "update" statement, which can possibly do "bulk" ( or multi ) processing.

What you want is [**`findByIdAndUpdate()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) or [**`findOneAndUpdate()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate). These methods return the either the original document or the modified document, according to the arguments you give.

```
add: function(req, res) {
    models.Team.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.tid,
        { $addToSet: { players: req.body } },
        function(err, newPlayer){
            if (err) {
                res.json({error: 'Error.'});
            } else {
                res.json(newPlayer);
            }
        }
    );
},
```

Comment: I see, but now the response is null?

Comment: I am confused because before I added a response it made it to the database now it wont even make it there anymore.

Comment: @Mike which means that the `_id` value is not being found and nothing is being updated. Check for your errors there.

Comment: Okay, I saw someone else said the same thing on a post here on stackoverflow, Ill test that out, but it seems the req.params.tid is returning the _id of the team in the database... Ill gear my attention to that... :)

Comment: @Mike actually all your last question showed was that a statement was passing through the Mongoose logger, it never said the database returned anything

Comment: @Mike Much as I had to explain to your colleauge ( I presume because the schema is exactly the same) this is not a chat room, it is intended as a knowledgebase not just directed at your current question but for future users to reference. We all have other things to work on. There should be more than enough information here for you to work out your issues without commenting on every turn. Chatting on every point serves no benefit to the community.